# OpenAL and Windows 10. Device is always 'Generic Software' and 'Generic Hardware'

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openal

Does anyone know how to manually change the name or where OpenAL gets the device names from ?
The sound card supports OpenAL if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick test:

```
std::cout << "Initialized " << alcGetString(device, ALC_ALL_DEVICES_SPECIFIER) << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenAL Soft version: " << alGetString(AL_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9PkS.png)

[Where it gets the information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxSaf.png)

You'll also find it in Device Manager -> Sound, video and game controllers.

Personally, I can choose between 3 output sources in Windows:

- Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)
- Headset Earphone (2 - DUALSHOCK 4 USB Wireless)
- DELL U2417H (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)

If I choose any of these in Windows 10, `alcGetString()` will return it correctly. The last entry is my monitor's speakers and the one in the middle is the audio jack from my DualShock 4 controller.

**Edit:** Now I remember. You're using OpenAL 1.1, i.e. "Legacy" OpenAL *(which hasn't been updated since 2006)*, not OpenAL Soft. It said the same thing for me when I tried it a few months ago. I mean, it still works. There were a ton of games released with it, which means it will most likely continue to work for the next few decades, but you really should swtich to OpenAL Soft. It's the open source re-creation of OpenAL based on the official SVN, and pretty much 100% backwards compatible with OpenAL (plus some newer features like ambisonics and HRTF).